# How to generate `by lazy` using KotlinPoet

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I want to generate code like this:

```
class B private constructor() : A {

    companion object {
        val instance: B by lazy(mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED) {
            B()
        }
    }
}
```

Using KotlinPoet:

```
private fun genCompanionObject() = TypeSpec.companionObjectBuilder()
        .addProperty(PropertySpec.builder("instance", A::class.java).build()).build()
```

How to generate `by lazy(mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED)`? I can  not find some useful APIs in [document](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `PropertySpec.Builder.delegate` methods. You provide a `CodeBlock` representing the initializer that represents the delegate.

Specifically for the code you want:

```
.delegate(CodeBlock.builder()
    .beginControlFlow("lazy(mode = %T.SYNCHRONIZED)", LazyThreadSafetyMode::class.asTypeName())
    .add("B()") // Or however you want to implement this
    .endControlFlow()
    .build())
```

Comment: You are so great,  I will have a try.